# Format text within a cell in Excel using Font.Characters

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, character, cell

I am trying to format text within a cell in Excel.

Using the Characters property, I specify a small range of characters within the text to be made Bold.

The whole of the text, from the first character in my range of characters to the end of the text is being made bold.

```vb
Private Sub TestFormatting()

    Dim TSheet As Worksheet
    Set TSheet = Worksheets("Test")
    
    TSheet.Cells(5, 1) = "This is some text" & vbLf & "This is some more text"
    
    With TSheet.Cells(5, 1)
        For i = 3 To 5
            .Characters(i).Font.Bold = True
        Next i
    End With
    
End Sub
```

The result is:
This **is some text

This is some more text**

I only asked for the characters 3 to 5 to be Bold.

Changing the code to:

```vb
Private Sub TestFormatting()

    Dim TSheet As Worksheet
    Set TSheet = Worksheets("Test")
    
    TSheet.Cells(5, 1) = "This is some text" & vbLf & "This is some more text"
    
    With TSheet.Cells(5, 1)
        For i = 3 To 5
            .Characters(i).Font.Bold = True
        Next i
        For i = 30 To 32
            .Characters(i).Font.Bold = False
        Next i
    End With
    
End Sub
```

The result is:
This **is some text

This is som**e more text

In both cases, the change is applied to the whole text from the first character in the For loop to the end of the text, ignoring that I only want the 3 characters to be formatted.

Answer (score 1):

[Use Characters (start, length), where start is the start character number and length is the number of characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.characters):

```
TSheet.Cells(5, 1).Characters(3, 3).Font.Bold = True
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I wanted. Note to self: "Look at the documentation!!"